# How to access multiple copies of wsgi site on server

Tags: apache, flask, wsgi

I have a Flask web site providing a service on an apache server, and now would like to run another copy of the code base for testing purposes on the same server (a different svn branch). So, I've installed the codebase in a different place on the server, and added another WSGIScriptAlias entry, referencing the test codebase, to the apache conf file:

```
# Entry point for the user web interface:
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /blah/blah/wsgi_entry.py

# Entry point for the test branch of the user web interface:
WSGIScriptAlias /mysiteTEST /blah/blah/testBranch/wsgi_entry.py
```

I was hoping that sending the browser to "mysiteTEST" instead of the usual "mysite" would have me running the code in the test branch. However it runs the original code, presumably because the wsgi_entry.py simply does something like:

```
from my_main_module import app as application
```

and where it's looking for my_main_module is presumably the python path set in the apache config, like so:

```
WSGIPythonPath /blah/blah/main_code_place
```

Which is correct for the main site, but I want to mysiteTEST to be running the modules in the test branch location.  So perhaps I can override the python path somehow in the testBranch/wsgi_entry.py (and perhaps not?), but is there a simpler way that I can manage this in the apache config?  I.e. can I somehow specify one WSGIPythonPath for /mysite, and another for /mysiteTEST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by adding a single line to modify the path in the wsgi entry point for the alternate code version (i.e. the file referenced in the apache config line "WSGIScriptAlias /mysiteTEST /blah/blah/testBranch/wsgi_entry.py" in my example). The line overrides the wsgi configured python search path. Not the apache config only solution I wanted, but it's only a single line addition and it does the job:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '<path for alternate code modules>')    
from my_main_module import app as application
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up multiple virtualhosts:

```
<VirtualHost your.ip:80>
ServerName blahblah
ServerAdmin blahblah@blah.com
WSGIDaemonProcess blahblah user=b group=lah threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /blah/blah/wsgi_entry.py

<Directory /blah/blah>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    WSGIProcessGroup blahblah
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost your.ip:80>
ServerName blahblahTEST
ServerAdmin blahblah@blah.com
WSGIDaemonProcess blahblahtest user=b group=lah threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /mysiteTEST /blah/blah/testBranch/wsgi_entry.py

<Directory /blah/blah/testBranch>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    WSGIProcessGroup blahblah
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Not sure all the other settings are applicable to you but as a whole, this should get you going.

Comment: Thanks, but this looks like it won't work. I started set up separate virtual host, but it looks like the WSGIPythonPath directive cannot be specified within a virtual host context:

`WSGIPythonPath cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section`

Comment: Move the WSGIPythonPath line outside of the VirtualHost section

Comment: The cause of the problem is that the WSGIPythonPath is common to the two codebases - which are identical in the names of the modules. So moving the WSGIPythonPath to global scope will not provide a solution.